# listview and option menu

Tags: android, menu

how to show the option menu when click to row of listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`openOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) from your ListActivity's [`onListItemClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29).

Comment: i have code public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
        { 
         createNote();
            return true;
          }
        case CALL_ID:
     {
          AdapterContextMenuInfo info2 = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
              String phone=mDbHelper.getPhone(info2.id);
             String toDial="tel:"+phone.toString();

    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(toDial)));
            return true;
        
     }
       
    }